# Dask to_parquet throws exception "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

The following Dask code attempts to store a dataframe in parquet, read it again, add a column, and store again the dataframe with the column added.

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'height': [6.21, 5.12, 5.85],
    'weight': [150, 126, 133]
})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=3) 
ddf.to_parquet('C:\\temp\\test3', engine='pyarrow', overwrite=True)
ddf2 = dd.read_parquet('C:\\temp\\test3') 
ddf2['new_column'] = 1
ddf2.to_parquet('C:\\temp\\test3', engine='pyarrow', overwrite=True) # <- this one fails
```

The error I get is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/temp/test3/part.0.parquet'
```

If I check directory `temp3` is empty.

I think that when the second `to_parquet` is executed, since `overwrite=True` it does an implicit `compute()` and the process starts in the `read_parquet`, but since overwrite deleted the files it doesn't find it. Is that the case?

In any way, how to make this work? Note that in the real scenario the dataframe doesn't fit in memory.

**UPDATE**

I'm not trying to update the parquet file, I need to write it again overwriting the existing one.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend reading & writing to the same file, especially if the file doesn't fit in memory. dask uses [lazy execution](https://tutorial.dask.org/01x_lazy.html), and the file won't be *read* until it's required by the next *write* operation. So your read may be interrupted by the write to the same directory. Also - please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors.

Comment: I need to add a column to a large parquet file. What’s the best approach to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append a new column to an existing parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812780/append-a-new-column-to-an-existing-parquet-file)

Comment: short answer: you can't. this just isn't what parquet is designed for.

Comment: I know that I cannot update the parquet file, that’s why I tried to write it again with the added column, overwriting its content. How can that be done in dask?

Comment: You should write to a new directory and remove the old one when done. fsspec's transactions could handle this for you, but I don't think it's worth it here.

Comment: Yes, that worked, after the `to_parquet` I executed `shutil.rmtree(old_path)`

Comment: @ps0604 I'm glad it worked. :) Would you mind adding an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, use a different file name when you do a `to_parquet` and then delete the old parquet directory:

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=3) 
ddf.to_parquet('C:\\temp\\OLD_FILE_NAME', engine='pyarrow', overwrite=True)
ddf2 = dd.read_parquet('C:\\temp\\OLD_FILE_NAME') 
ddf2['new_column'] = 1
ddf2.to_parquet('C:\\temp\\NEW_FILE_NAME', engine='pyarrow', overwrite=True)

path_to_delete = os.path.dirname('C:\\temp\\OLD_FILE_NAME\\') 
shutil.rmtree(path_to_delete)
```